# Regex to find a specific pattern in code and replace it with a new pattern

Tags: regex, find-replace, recursive-regex

I’m new to regex and I can’t find a way to do what I want. Let me explain.
I have some piece of code that looks like this in Notepad++:

```
set a [expr $sumy+1]
set b [[expr $sumy+1] [expr $sumy+2] [expr $sumy+3]]
set c [expr $sumy+[lindex $coords 1]]
set d [expr [lindex [$ret] 2] + $Alpha]
set e [string range $SECNAME 0 [expr [string first - $SECNAME] -1] ]
```

And I have to remplace each [expr … ] pattern by [expr {…}] (and if brackets are already there, it must not be replaced) :

```
set a [expr {$sumy+1}]
set b [[expr {$sumy+1}] [expr {$sumy+2}] [expr {$sumy+3}]]
set c [expr {$sumy+[lindex $coords 1]}]
set d [expr {[lindex [$ret] 2] + $Alpha}]
set e [string range $SECNAME 0 [expr {[string first - $SECNAME] -1}] ]
```

To do the job, I’m using regex to find each expr pattern and replace it with the new one. For cases a and b, this regex works fine :

Find : `(\[expr\s+)([^{][^\]]*)(\])` 
Replace : `\1{\2}\3`

For cases c and d, I’m using this one :

Find : `((\[expr\s+)([^{][^\].*\]]*)(\].*)(\]))` 
Replace : `\1{\2\3}\4`
(https://regex101.com/r/ZU6mNd/1)

But I don’t find a way to match properly the expr pattern for case e. Can anyone help me with that ?
I was also wondering if there is a way to match all the cases with a single regex ? Maybe with recursion ?

Thanks !

Comment: `(\[expr\s+)((?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?2))*])|[^][{}])*)(])` => `$1{$2}$4`, see https://regex101.com/r/xsKE5u/2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks ! It works perfectly in regex101 ! However, when I try in Notepad++ to find all expr in a file with this regex, it works fine until the first expr like case c (ending with ]]), any idea why ? But anyway, many thanks, you still save me a lot of time !

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo, it must be `(?3)`

Comment: Now it’s also working perfectly in Notepad ! Many Thanks ! I’m curious, can you explain how the middle part of the regex is working ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**:       `(\[expr\s+)((?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?3))*])|[^][{}])*)(])` 
**Replace With**: `$1{$2}$4`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsKE5u/3). *Details*:

- `(\[expr\s+)` - Group 1:
- `((?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?3))*])|[^][{}])*)` - Group 2: zero or more occurrences of

  - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?3))*])` - Group 3: `[`, then zero or more sequences of any one or more chars other than `[` and `]` or Group 3 pattern recursed, and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^][{}]` - a char other than `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`
- `(])` - Group 4:  a `]` char.

Demo screenshot:

[image]